# How to validate DropdowList in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Please help me this problem.
I can't validate for DropdownList for My Project.
My Model used DataAnnontation:

```
public class Category
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, Some code for Create View:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)   
    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", String.Empty) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CategoryId)</td>
}
```

Comment: You should use @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.CategoryList), where CategoryList is the complete list of categories ie a Name/Value object

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@html.DropDownListFor()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Model

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.CategoryId, 
        new SelectList(Model.Categories, "ID", "CategoryName"), 
        "-- Please select a category --"
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CategoryId)
}
```